# attributeerror: 'AioClientCreator' object has no attribute '_register_lazy_block_unknown_fips_pseudo_regions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Recently, I have started to occupy the *AWS* platform, but when trying to occupy `Sagemaker`, the following error I don't know if it is because of `Sagemaker` or if it has something to do with ´Parquet Dataset´:

```py
session = sagemaker.Session()
region = boto3.Session().region_name
role = get_execution_role()

import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

bucket = 's3://xx'

df = pq.ParquetDataset(bucket, filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

Up to this point, everything loads fine, but I have the following error

```
Attributeerror: 'AioClientCreator' object has no attribute '_register_lazy_block_unknown_fips_pseudo_regions'
```

[image: AttributeError]

I do not know, what could be the error

Answer (score 13):

Same here. According to [this issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/2568), it's having to do with botocore removing this function.

> This function in question (_register_lazy_block_unknown_fips_pseudo_regions) was intentionally removed as it was used to prevent unknown/new region endpoint variants from actually being used to make API calls while allowing the client to be constructed, and seems to have been added to aibotocore inadvertently.

I was able to resolve the issue by using `botocore==1.22.5`.

---

Edit:

I've since tried again to get everything working together. Here is my `Pipfile` which seems to work without throwing errors like those reported by @Drwhit. I believe that error is coming from [this issue](https://github.com/fsspec/s3fs/issues/357).

```
s3fs = {version = "~=2021.4", extras = ["boto3"]}
aiohttp = "==3.7.2"
botocore = "==1.22.8"
aiobotocore = "==2.0.1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, anyway updating package aiobotocore, fix the problem.

Comment: You saved me.. 2 hours fighting this problem, and finally downgrading to 1.22.5 worked. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what versions of boto3 and aiobotocore you are using?  when I try to downgrade to botocore1.22.5 I get the following message: 

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
boto3 1.20.24 requires botocore<1.24.0,>=1.23.24, but you have botocore 1.22.5 which is incompatible.
aiobotocore 2.0.1 requires botocore<1.22.9,>=1.22.8, but you have botocore 1.22.5 which is incompatible.

Answer (score 6):

For making this work, in an environment with some libraries already installed, I needed to issue some uninstall commands, before installing the old boto3 version:

```
pip uninstall boto3
pip uninstall botocore
pip uninstall aiobotocore
```

Then issued this one:

```
pip install boto3==1.17.106
```

...and finally worked.

Should any conflict issue arises when installing that specific boto3 version, just uninstall the package that is in conflict (happened to me with a version of sagemaker). If you need it, reinstall after installing boto3 old version. No guarantee that will work at the end; trial and error will help.

When done, issue `pip list`, so you can get the complete list of versions that work, and put it with the appropriate syntax changes into a `requirements.txt` file, so you can build your environment later.